# Screen Captures Using Unity and ARKit

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, textures, arkit

I'm taking a screenshot in a Unity application using

`ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot ("screenshot.png", 2);`

But the AR background being rendered by ARKit ends up being completely black with other GameObjects rendering correctly (floating in black space).

Have others encountered this issue?
Is there a known workaround?

Answer (score 2):

There are too many bugs with `ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot`. Do not use this function to preform any screenshot in Unity at this moment. It's not just on iOS, there are also bug on with this function in the Editor.

Here is a remake of that function that can take screenshot in png, jpeg or exr format.

```
IEnumerator CaptureScreenshot(string filename, ScreenshotFormat screenshotFormat)
{
    //Wait for end of frame
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    Texture2D screenImage = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height);
    //Get Image from screen
    screenImage.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0);
    screenImage.Apply();

    string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "images");
    byte[] imageBytes = null;

    //Convert to png/jpeg/exr
    if (screenshotFormat == ScreenshotFormat.PNG)
    {
        filePath = Path.Combine(filePath, filename + ".png");
        createDir(filePath);
        imageBytes = screenImage.EncodeToPNG();
    }
    else if (screenshotFormat == ScreenshotFormat.JPEG)
    {
        filePath = Path.Combine(filePath, filename + ".jpeg");
        createDir(filePath);
        imageBytes = screenImage.EncodeToJPG();
    }
    else if (screenshotFormat == ScreenshotFormat.EXR)
    {
        filePath = Path.Combine(filePath, filename + ".exr");
        createDir(filePath);
        imageBytes = screenImage.EncodeToEXR();
    }

    //Save image to file
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, imageBytes);
    Debug.Log("Saved Data to: " + filePath.Replace("/", "\\"));
}

void createDir(string dir)
{
    //Create Directory if it does not exist
    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(dir)))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(dir));
    }
}

public enum ScreenshotFormat
{
    PNG, JPEG, EXR
}
```

**USAGE**:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(CaptureScreenshot("screenshot", ScreenshotFormat.PNG));
}
```